# Add a table row dynamically in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My table looks like this:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

then I have a button:

```
<input id="btn2" value="add New row" type="button"/>
```

the JQuery code is like this:

```
$('#btn2').click(function () {
    var v_html = $('#table1 tr').first();
    $('#table1').append(v_html);

});
```

It's not working for me, because the content in the first row is dynamic and I cannot hard code in the JQuery. I just want to copy first `<tr>` and append it to last position in the table.

It should be like this:

```
<table id="table1">
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>        
    </tr>
</table>
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) to copy a row

```
$('#btn2').click(function () {
    var $row = $('#table1 tr').first().clone();
    $('#table1').append($row);

});
```

Comment: is it possible to get the $('#table1 tr').first().html() and append it ?

Comment: @ILikeToMoveItMoveIt would either need to get outerHTML or get the html() and create a new `<tr>` to put it in. Simpler to use clone()